# Folder Tree Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement a tree list with data that I get from an API. Assuming I get the data from the api successfully, how would I have my layout look? the tree must show all sub trees trees etc. So it must show down the last level. Sort of like this:

[image]

The user will be able to select/deselect a folder, and I must then automatically select/deselect all its sub channels. So that would be presented with a checkbox

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/channel_row"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_channel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:checked="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/channel_text"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" 
        android:textSize="25sp" >       
    </TextView>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: I would rather use listviews that has different levels. Example : you have all the folders in your root in a listview, when a item is clicked it builds a new list of the contents of that folder ect. You can build a tree list but it can become complicated and you will have to use a ViewGroup if you want to do it properly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617388/browse-button-required/5617469#5617469 might help you